# unable to get log or execution in getView() cause empty layout display

Tags: android

I have searched over the google, but still stuck in my problem. I m new to android and facing a issue where I m using custom adapter + pull down to refresh features.

The pull down to refresh I get from this source.
https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh

and it is working fine. But when I go use custom adapter with my code below: it failed to display but when I print log get count it shows 5 . which mean got data

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Dishes> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private List<Dishes> items;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context,int resource, List<Dishes> items) {

        super(context, resource, items);
        this.items = items;
        Log.i("testing", String.valueOf(items.size()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return items.size();

    };

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.i("testing", "testingxxxx");
        View v = convertView;
        //packageHolder holder = null;

        if (v == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);

        }

        Dishes p = items.get(position);
        Log.i("testing", p.name+"----"+p.ImageId);
        if (p != null) {


            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.package_name);
            TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.package_desp);
            TextView tt3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.package_price);

            if (tt != null) {
                tt.setText(p.name);
            }
            if (tt1 != null) {
                tt1.setText(p.description);
            }
            if (tt3 != null) {
                tt3.setText(p.price);
            }
        }

        return v;

    }
```

Below code is where I pass the object to customadapter class.. Advise needed. I try get Count it shows got...why?

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){

    Dishes dishes = new Dishes(R.drawable.ic_launcher, DishesName[i], DishesDescription[i], Price[i]);
    aList.add(dishes);
}

CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.id.list,aList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you setting the adapter to listview ,

`myListVIew.setAdapter(adapter);`

getView() is called for each item in the list you pass to your adapter. It is called when you set adapter. When getView() is finished the next line after setAdapter(myAdapter) is called

Comment: Hi rahul Yes I did
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
but still empty shown...what did I miss out?
for ur info, I didnot put <listview> tag in xml layout. is that ok?